# Replacing multiple values in excel sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, vlookup, vba

I have two sheets

(1) this one with group id and group description

(2) this contains only group description in multiple columns.

I need to replace all the group description in sheet 2 across all columns with the group id.

SHEET 1

```
group id| group discription
   1    |  abcd
   2    |  xyzs
   3    |  ghtv
```

SHEET 2

```
group discription
abcd|xyzs|ghtv|gtsx
adds|gtfc|gtui|vbnm
qwas|lmko|zxcd|ytru
```

SHEET 3 REsult sheet I want looks like this

```
 1|2|3|9
 5|4|8|0
 6|7|3|0
```

I have large data. can anyone suggest how to do this

Comment: Can you please add, what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use a `VLOOKUP` but to do this you need to re-order your columns in Sheet 1:

```
group description | group id
   abcd           |  1
   xyzs           |  2
   ghtv           |  3
```

Then in `Sheet3`:

```
=VLOOKUP(Sheet2!A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$B$3,2,FALSE)
```

Where:

- `Sheet2!A1` references the value to be looked up in `Sheet2`
- `Sheet1!$A$1:$B$3` is your reference lookup table in `Sheet1`